# R : Trying to have interaction in regression model where the response is linear for 1 level of interaction and 1/x for the other level of interaction

Tags: r, regression, interaction

For the mtcars dataset, if you clean up the dataframe to mtcars2 as shown below

```
mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, {
  vs <- factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  am <- factor(am, labels = c("automatic", "manual"))
  cyl  <- ordered(cyl)
  gear <- ordered(gear)
  carb <- ordered(carb)
})
```

and then plot this :

```
ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x=disp, y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_grid(~am)
```

you can see that the response of disp is linear for am = automatic and, I am hypothesizing, is 1/x for am = manual.

I am trying to write that in the linear model that I am building in R but I cannot do it.

This is my attempt at it :

I make sure to set automatic as the base/reference level :

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars2 %>%
  mutate(am = relevel(am, ref = "automatic"))
```

then I write the model :

`model4disp<-lm(data=mtcars2, mpg~am + disp +disp*am +I(1/disp)*am)`

but it gives me the term "1/disp"  which I do not want, as I pointed out, I only want a "1/disp" response for when am = manual.  Basically, in basic math, I want this :

`y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x1x2 + b4(1/x1)x2` 
where

```
x1 is a dummy variable where x1 = 1 if its manual, and x1 = 0 if automatic
x2 = disp
y = mpg
```

How can I do that???

Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't believe you have adequate data to support your visual impression of a difference in functional form of the relationship between the two types of transmission. I suspect a principled approach to constructing a single regression analysis would involve a nonlinear model, rather than sticking with linear regression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I agree that the hypothesis  1/disp for am = manual is not very based on much, but I do see a use for generating the coefficients the way I have defined them in my math equation (if the pvalue for the terms end up being significant).  But mostly, I want to learn how to create these kinds of interactions R.

Comment: As I said before I do it think you are describing a problem that can be addressed in a linear modeling framework. I think you need statistical assistance in formulating a model that can be estimated in a nonlinear framework.